# SQL ALL COMMAND, SUBQUERY RETURNS NULL BUT OUTPUT GIVES ALL RECORDS

Tags: mysql, sql, teradata

Using `ALL` command in SQL, the subquery returns NULL values but the query is giving all the records in the table.

```
SELECT * FROM STORES
WHERE STORE_NUMBER = ALL(SELECT STORE_NUMBER FROM STORES WHERE STORE_NUMBER>10000)
```

The Subquery:

```
SELECT STORE_NUMBER FROM STORES WHERE STORE_NUMBER>10000
```

Returns 0 records

But when I run the whole query it gives me all the records in the `Stores` table. Isn't it supposed to give NULL values?

Comment: Please don't write in all caps, its considered shouting; people don't want to help when they are being shouted at.

Comment: MySQL ot Teradata?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this is how `= ALL` is supposed to work according to Stnadrad SQL: if the subquery returns no rows (or all returned rows share the same value) the condition is evaluated to `TRUE`.

But why do you want to use `= ALL`, it's very uncommon?